# Count combinations of two variables excluding rows that repeat ID

Tags: r, database, dplyr

I have a data on countries and want to summarize it and create a table.

```
> head(data)
         country year score members
              A 1989     0       7
              A 1990     0       7
              A 1991     0       7
              A 1992     0       7
              A 1993     0       7
              A 1994     0       7
```

The table should show the relationship between country "score" and the number of "members" –  put differently, I want to see how many states with score 0,1 or 2 have "members"(ranging from 1 to 7).

I want to set it like this:

```
score members==1 members==2 members==3 members==4 members==5 members==6 members==7
0        1          0
1        2          0
2        0          1  and so on..
```

To do this I run the following:

```
library(dplyr)
    table <- data %>%
      group_by(score) %>% 
      summarise(
        m1    = sum(members==1, na.rm=TRUE),
        m2    = sum(members==2, na.rm=TRUE),
        m3    = sum(members==3, na.rm=TRUE),
        m4    = sum(members==4, na.rm=TRUE),
        m5    = sum(members==5, na.rm=TRUE),
        m6    = sum(members==6, na.rm=TRUE),
        m7    = sum(members==7, na.rm=TRUE)

      )
```

This gives:

```
    score    m1    m2    m3    m4    m5    m6    m7
        0     0     2     0     0     0     3    30
        1    15     3    11    11     3    18     3
        2     3     0     2     2     0     6     9
.
.
```

I need a little help here. As you see it has calculated the total number of observations, whereas I want to count each country only once.

How do I summarize this data to have the total number of countries for each members-level?

Here's a sample of my data for reproducibility:

```
data <-
structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), 
    year = c(1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 
    1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
    2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2010L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
    1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 
    2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
    2011L, 1989L, 1991L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1999L, 
    2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
    2010L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 
    1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
    2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 
    1994L, 1995L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
    2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2010L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 
    1994L, 1995L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
    2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2010L), score = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), members = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("country", "year", "score", 
"members"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -121L))
```

Comment: `with(data, table(score, members))`

Comment: or `with(data, table(score, members, country))` if it has to be per country

Comment: what exactly is your desired output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the OP is using `dplyr` methods, we can do this by grouping with 'score', 'members' to get the number of elements (`n()`), and then `spread` (from `tidyr`) to reshape it to 'wide' format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
    group_by(score, members) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(members = paste0("m", members)) %>%
    spread(members, n, fill = 0)
#  score    m1    m2    m3    m4    m5    m6    m7
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0     0     2     0     0     0     3    30
#2     1    15     3    11    11     3    18     3
#3     2     3     0     2     2     0     6     9
```

If we need to also get the counts by 'country', just add 'country' in the `group_by`

```
data %>%
    group_by(country, score, members) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(members = paste0("m", members)) %>%
    spread(members, n, fill = 0)
```

---

If the expected output is the one showed in the other posts, an option using `data.table` would be to convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data`), and `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide' specifying the `fun.aggregate` as `uniqueN` of the 'value.var' variable i.e. 'country' where `uniqueN` returns the `length` of `unique` elements in the 'country' column.  The `fill=0` specifies to occupy 0 for those combinations that are not available.  By default, it returns as NA.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(data), score~members, value.var= 'country', fun.aggregate = uniqueN, fill = 0)   
#   score 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
#1:     0 0 1 0 0 0 1 2
#2:     1 1 1 2 2 1 3 2
#3:     2 1 0 1 2 0 1 1
```

Comment: so that is the output the OP is getting but don't want to get... : *as you see it has calculated the total number of observations and not per country*

Comment: yes (and I really see the point of 2 packages and a lot of lines to get the same btw) but still, based on the OP remark, I don't think it is what they want

Comment: `group_by(score, members) %>% summarise(n = n())` can be written as `count(score, members)`

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need this:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(aggregate(country~score+members, data=data, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))), 
      score~members, value.var="country", fill=0L)
#  score 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
#1     0 0 1 0 0 0 1 2
#2     1 1 1 2 2 1 3 2
#3     2 1 0 1 2 0 1 1
```

Or, to put it the `dplyr`/`tidyr` way:

```
data %>% 
     group_by(members, score) %>% 
     summarise(n=n_distinct(country)) %>% 
     spread(members, n, fill=0L)

## A tibble: 3 x 8
#  score     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
#* <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     2
#2     1     1     1     2     2     1     3     2
#3     2     1     0     1     2     0     1     1
```

Comment: @akrun come on, we just didn't understand the Q the same way, I give an hint of what I thought was what the OP wanted. We don't get the same output except that now, based on my answer, you put the option to get the other output...

Comment: I think it is better to post the `n_distinct(country)` as it is the dplyr way.  I will delete mine.  I thought of posting it bcz of your comment on my answer below

Answer (score 2):

It seems the crux of the issue is having the duplicated rows for each year?  In which case you can remove them with `distinct`, then it's a simple crosstab.  You could use the `%$%` exposition pipe from magrittr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
data %>%
  distinct(country, score, members) %$%
  table(score, members)

     members
score 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
    0 0 1 0 0 0 1 2
    1 1 1 2 2 1 3 2
    2 1 0 1 2 0 1 1
```

Or a regular pipe and `tabyl` from the janitor package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
data %>%
  distinct(country, score, members) %>%
  tabyl(score, members)

 score 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
     0 0 1 0 0 0 1 2
     1 1 1 2 2 1 3 2
     2 1 0 1 2 0 1 1
```